# Making a graph or network interactively over an image

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, computational-geometry, mesh, drawing

Given an image, is it possible to manually draw a graph over it? For example, taking the following image:

[image]

I want to manually pick the vertices and draw the edges in a "Paint-like" manner to get, for example,

[image]

By manually I mean literally using the mouse to select the vertices.

Any ideas?

**Note:** This is the "easy" solution to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214262/getting-cell-edges-from-a-picture), where I intend to build an automatic image processing program. For now, however, a manual solution would suffice.

Comment: Have a look at `LocatorPane`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

There are many ways to do this, modifying, improving my method or doing a completely different thing. My goal here is to show a very basic idea that should give you a start. `LocatorPane` and `Manipulate` give means of interactive addition/deletion and dragging of points in 2D plane. The problem is how to add an edge -- there has to be interaction between 2 points. The idea used here is the following:

- Assume empty initial list of edges
- Trigger for making an edge is when 2 points become close enough
- Accumulate such edges and build a graph
- Jump through various hoops for proper sorting, duplicate deletion, etc.

Let's start from importing image:

```
i=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5PX3.png"];
```

defining a function:

```
makeEDGEs[r_][pts_]:=
UndirectedEdge@@@Cases[Union[Sort/@Nearest[pts->"Index",pts,{2,r}]],{_,_}]
```

Note "Index" property usage, which important, because you need to build edges from indexes of points - not from point coordinates. Read docs on all these functions to understand how it works. `r` defines distance threshold between the points -- if you go under it an edge will be created. Here is an easy interactive app that uses above function to accumulate edges:

```
Clear[edges]
edges={};
Manipulate[
edges=Union[edges~Join~makeEDGEs[10][pts]];
g=Graph[Range[Length[pts]],edges,
    VertexCoordinates->pts,
    VertexSize->5{1,1},VertexStyle->Red,
    EdgeStyle->Directive[Thickness[.01],Black]];
Show[i,g],
{{pts,{{100,100},{100,150},{150,100}}},
Appearance->None,Locator,LocatorAutoCreate->True}]
```

You are adding a point with CMD+CLICK action. Note there are many possible improvements. For instance, optimization for speed. Or "undo" action -- you cal also remove a point with CMD+CLICK action, but this will destroy the graph due to ordering and numbering issues, - so there is no undo for now -- up to you to make it. Cool thing about it is - the graph object is easy to get separately and compute with:

```
{g, MatrixPlot[AdjacencyMatrix[g]]}
```

[image]

### Related Resources

> **Constructing and Manipulating Graphs**
>
> https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConstructingAndManipulatingGraphs

Also take a look at this legacy tool:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
GraphEdit[]
```

Comment: Very nice!  When copying your code that starts with "Clear[edges]", it complains because "i" is not defined so "Show[i,g]" has a problem.  Did I miss a piece of code that needs to be run?

Comment: Thanks @MarkR, yes I added now definition of `i`, it is the image.

Comment: Thanks for including the image.  I really like this.

Comment: This is REALLY COOL, Vitaliy! Can you clarify how this is “connecting” the vertexes with the edges from just touching them together, though? I can’t readily tell, is it from the `LocatorAutoCreate->True`?

Comment: Thanks @CATrevillian :-) Function `makeEDGEs` literally makes an edge for a set of points when any 2 come close enough. `Manipulate` dynamically updates everything inside it while you dragging locators and triggers action of `makeEDGEs`.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov very cool stuff, thanks!