# Adding geometrical boundary edges to a graph or closing the embedding of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mesh, lattices

Consider the following graph `g`

[image]

I want to "close" it by adding the following edges

[image]

Alternatively, I would also be happy with something like

[image]

where I've added four "corner" vertices.

Now, this question is, in a way, a follow up to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/214272/64001), where I initially have a picture on which I draw a graph, as follows

[image]

Is it possible to turn the picture into a rectangle-shaped graph and then join them in somehow? This would lead to something like the second example.

Alternatively, I also thought about simply uniting 1-degree vertices that are close to each other, creating the first example graph.

In the end, I want a graph that defines a mesh, thus the need of "closing" the graph in this fashion. Ideally, I want `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[g] = True` for the closed graph.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1:** Note that my goal is to be able to do this for general graphs. For example, considering the graph

[image]

I want to get something like

[image]

I guess using something like `ConvexHull` (which doesn't correspond to what is drawn) in some matter could help my goal, but at this point I'm entirely sure how.

**Edit 2:** In order to be more practical consider the graph given by

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 13, 
   7 \[UndirectedEdge] 14, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 20, 
   10 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 21, 
   11 \[UndirectedEdge] 25, 12 \[UndirectedEdge] 18, 
   12 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 13 \[UndirectedEdge] 18, 
   13 \[UndirectedEdge] 27, 14 \[UndirectedEdge] 15, 
   14 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 16 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 
   17 \[UndirectedEdge] 23, 18 \[UndirectedEdge] 24, 
   19 \[UndirectedEdge] 22, 20 \[UndirectedEdge] 21, 
   20 \[UndirectedEdge] 27, 21 \[UndirectedEdge] 34, 
   22 \[UndirectedEdge] 26, 22 \[UndirectedEdge] 29, 
   23 \[UndirectedEdge] 31, 23 \[UndirectedEdge] 33, 
   24 \[UndirectedEdge] 29, 24 \[UndirectedEdge] 30, 
   25 \[UndirectedEdge] 31, 25 \[UndirectedEdge] 34, 
   27 \[UndirectedEdge] 28, 28 \[UndirectedEdge] 32, 
   28 \[UndirectedEdge] 38, 29 \[UndirectedEdge] 37, 
   30 \[UndirectedEdge] 32, 30 \[UndirectedEdge] 35, 
   31 \[UndirectedEdge] 39, 32 \[UndirectedEdge] 41, 
   34 \[UndirectedEdge] 36, 35 \[UndirectedEdge] 42, 
   35 \[UndirectedEdge] 44, 36 \[UndirectedEdge] 45, 
   36 \[UndirectedEdge] 54, 37 \[UndirectedEdge] 40, 
   37 \[UndirectedEdge] 44, 38 \[UndirectedEdge] 45, 
   38 \[UndirectedEdge] 48, 39 \[UndirectedEdge] 47, 
   39 \[UndirectedEdge] 53, 41 \[UndirectedEdge] 42, 
   41 \[UndirectedEdge] 48, 42 \[UndirectedEdge] 56, 
   43 \[UndirectedEdge] 46, 44 \[UndirectedEdge] 51, 
   45 \[UndirectedEdge] 55, 46 \[UndirectedEdge] 47, 
   46 \[UndirectedEdge] 52, 47 \[UndirectedEdge] 49, 
   48 \[UndirectedEdge] 50},
  VertexCoordinates -> {{102.5`, 175.5`}, {84.5`, 152.5`}, {108.5`, 
     175.5`}, {133.5`, 153.5`}, {152.5`, 175.5`}, {244.5`, 
     175.5`}, {254.5`, 148.5`}, {43.5`, 174.5`}, {43.5`, 
     170.5`}, {196.5`, 174.5`}, {202.5`, 147.5`}, {297.5`, 
     174.5`}, {309.5`, 147.5`}, {63.5`, 148.5`}, {10.5`, 
     141.5`}, {143.5`, 117.5`}, {119.5`, 109.5`}, {67.5`, 
     94.5`}, {236.5`, 131.5`}, {293.5`, 127.5`}, {180.5`, 
     89.5`}, {312.5`, 146.5`}, {4.5`, 143.5`}, {18.5`, 
     97.5`}, {253.5`, 95.5`}, {301.5`, 98.5`}, {110.5`, 
     75.5`}, {313.5`, 93.5`}, {286.5`, 83.5`}, {52.5`, 80.5`}, {4.5`, 
     76.5`}, {236.5`, 82.5`}, {181.5`, 86.5`}, {187.5`, 
     80.5`}, {168.5`, 31.5`}, {297.5`, 37.5`}, {244.5`, 
     49.5`}, {59.5`, 29.5`}, {216.5`, 27.5`}, {125.5`, 
     38.5`}, {225.5`, 26.5`}, {280.5`, 23.5`}, {152.5`, 
     20.5`}, {110.5`, 3.5`}, {313.5`, 29.5`}, {199.5`, 7.5`}, {32.5`, 
     7.5`}, {85.5`, 3.5`}, {236.5`, 3.5`}, {4.5`, 25.5`}, {10.5`, 
     16.5`}, {281.5`, 4.5`}, {155.5`, 3.5`}, {4.5`, 3.5`}, {34.5`, 
     4.5`}, {199.5`, 4.5`}},
  VertexSize -> 3 {1, 1}, VertexStyle -> Red, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black]]
```

which yields the first graph `g`. Then, the code

```
hm = ConvexHullMesh[
      Transpose[
Select[{GraphEmbedding[g], VertexDegree[g]} // 
      Transpose, #[[2]] == 1 &]][[1]]]
gb = Graph[hm["Edges"], VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[hm], 
  VertexSize -> 3 {1, 1}, VertexStyle -> Red, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black]]
```

yields

[image]

Now, how do I merge both graphs? I tried `GraphUnion`, but I would need the correct `VertexCoordinates`. Could it be simply an ordering problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide the graph data so we can help you.

Comment: The data can be found in the linked answer.

Comment: Also, this is but an example graph, I want to be able to do it more generally. I will edit the question in order to make this point more clear.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but I provided the full data anyway (Edit 2). Now I simply need to join both graphs. Please take a look.

Comment: What is your definition of a graph? What is your definition of "closed" graph?

Comment: @Helena, you can find the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)
Regarding the ambiguous term "closed", I suggest you read my question carefully, as it's all explained there. A useful term is the convex hull to understand my question properly.

Comment: @samwolfe No reason to be condescending, I am trying to help you. The reason I am asking is because ConvexHull applies to a list of two dimensional points and does not really apply to Graphs as they are commonly defined.
As Szabolcs points out in their answer, there problem you are describing does seem to be a geometrical one and not a graph problem.

Comment: I am not condescending. Your questions were made without any context and I have no idea about your background, so I answered accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

This problem isn't really related to graphs. Graphs, by definition, only contain connectivity information. What you are asking for is a geometry problem, not a graph theory problem.

What you show in your example figure is a convex hull. `ConvexHullMesh` can compute it.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that could be the way to go (see edit). But can I apply the `ConvexHullMesh` to a graph?

Comment: No. As I said, it's a geometrical operation. If you post sample data, I will show you how to do it, and actually augment a `Graph` with new edges.

Comment: Please look at Edit 2. I managed to get what I wanted, now I simply need to join the two graphs.

Comment: I will, tomorrow. Sorry, too tired.

Comment: @samwolfe You got your answer from kglr. I would have likely come up with something very similar.

Comment: Thank you! I'm almost done, now I'm just getting a bit of a problem getting `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[g, 2] = True`. Though the graphs are merged, I still have degree-1 vertices, which I don't want.

Answer (score 5):

```
posToVertex = AssociationThread[GraphEmbedding[g], VertexList[g]];

newEdges =  Map[posToVertex, MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[GraphEmbedding[g]], 1] /. 
      Line -> Apply[UndirectedEdge], {-2}];

EdgeAdd[g, newEdges]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm still not getting `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[g, 2] = True`. Any idea why?

Comment: I am still getting vertices with degree one, when evaluating `VertexDegree[g]`.

Comment: It seems to me that what is happening is that the `ConvexHullMesh` naturally misses some degree-1 vertices and your graph simply has the illusion that there are no degree-1 vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The graph g in the example:

[image]

---

With direct application of `ConvexHullMesh` and usage of the generated `Lines` there are **missing edges** at the boundary. The **graph below colors edges randomly but** as we see there are **many supposed edges at the boundary** that are actually the **same edge** as they have the **same color**. They are simply long edges that traverse the vertices due to the imposed geometry for the graph.

[image]

With the **codes below** **all edges are included** depending on the definition one takes.

> **Definition A**
>
> The boundary is the set of degree 1 vertices that are not encircled by
> other vertices in the geometrical graph embedding."

In other words they are the outer vertices that are of degree 1. This definition works nicely in the example above as most of the outer vertices are of degree 1.

> **Definition B**
>
> The boundary is the set of vertices that belong to the convex hull.

Note that this might not be your preferred definition given that you gave a non convex example. In particular some of the outer degree 1 vertices will not be included in the boundary and so you are not guaranteed that `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[graph, 2]`. In particular this will not be the case below for the convex boundary.

**Definition A** : Focus on the degree 1 vertices

The image below is generated from the code in the last section.

*Note that randomly coloring the edges a few times, accidental same color adjacent edges are removed.*

[image]

**Definition B: focus on the convex hull**

The change is minor in this case as only the blue vertices are not on the convex hull. The change would be more significant for a "less convex" graph:

[image]

Nevertheless these are the edges for this definition:

Note that where the vertices are not included the color is the same on either side as the edge simply traverses the vertex without any connection. Those degree one vertices are not connected to the edge and so `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[graph, 2]` is false.

[image]

---

**Outline**

- **Issue with direct application of ConvexHull**
- **Possible solution**

---

### Issue with direct application of ConvexHull

**TL;DR :** The line segments from `ConvexHull` seem to pass through points that rest on the same line. Hence there are missing edges when one just adds the line segments.

From what I tested, the convex hull mesh does not seem to produce all the edges between graph vertices. See the image below that shows the added line segments from the convex hull:

```
{GraphEmbedding[g] // ConvexHullMesh // MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & // 
    Map[{RandomColor[], #} &], GraphEmbedding[g] // Map[Point]} // 
  Catenate // Graphics
```

[image]

This can also be checked with the graph:

```
HighlightGraph[new, Style[#, RandomColor[]] & /@ EdgeList@new]
```

[image]

There are colors that traverse vertices at the boundary.

Also

```
KVertexConnectedGraphQ[new, 2]
```

`(* False *)`

which OP does not seem to want.

---

### Possible solution

**TL;DR**: Extract vertices at the boundary either by their degree or whether they belong to the convex hull (may lead to different results depending on the graph), use [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) and [`PathGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PathGraph.html) to connect them and then add them to the original graph with a graph position to geometrical postion mapping.

#### Method 1: Exploit the vertex degree of the vertices at the boundary.

All of the degree 1 vertices in the example provided are "outer vertices" hence we shall not impose the constraint that the vertex should not be encircled by others. **For another graph one might have to add the no encircling constraint**.

Degree 1 vertices can be extracted using:

**Note:** (`…=\[Ellipsis]`)

```
boundary…vertices = 
 VertexList[g, _?(VertexDegree[g, #] == 1 &)];
```

Their geometric positions can be found using the rule:

```
VertexPos = Thread[VertexList[g] -> GraphEmbedding[g]];
```

Note: (`⎵=\[UnderBracket]`)

```
boundary…vertices⎵positions = 
 boundary…vertices /. VertexPos;
```

One may order these vertices along a path using [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html)

```
path…ordering = 
  FindCurvePath[boundary…vertices⎵positions];

path = boundary…vertices⎵positions[[path…ordering[[1]]]];
```

Then one may construct edges from those ordered points using [`PathGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PathGraph.html) and [`EdgeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeList.html). Note that we first had to order the edges before using `PathGraph`.

```
path⎵edges = path // PathGraph // EdgeList;
```

Those are written as spatial points we have to convert them back to vertex positions by inverting VertexPos above. We then add those edges to the original graph:

```
completed…graph = EdgeAdd[g, path⎵edges /. Reverse /@ VertexPos];
```

We can check the result with:

```
HighlightGraph[completed…graph, 
Style[#, RandomColor[]] & /@ EdgeList@completed…graph]
```

**Note**: some edges at the boundary might randomly have a similar color, evaluate the code again to change colors and check that the edges no longer have the same color.

[image]

```
KVertexConnectedGraphQ[completed…graph, 2]
```

`(* True *)`

#### Method 2: Extract points from the boundary of the convex hull.

**Note :** *Mainly only the code for boundary…vertices⎵positions is changed, the rest is copy pasted for those that did not read method 1 except for the end when I test `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[completed…graph, 2]` to be false. I will indicate when the rest is copy pasted other than the `KVertexConnectedGraphQ[completed…graph, 2]` test.*

The boundary of the convex hull as a list lines:

```
lines = ConvexHullMesh[GraphEmbedding[g]] // MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &;
```

Geometric positions of vertices in the graph can be found using the rule:

```
VertexPos = Thread[VertexList[g] -> GraphEmbedding[g]];
```

A function that checks whether a point belongs to the boundary:

```
boundaryPoint[point_] := AnyTrue[lines, RegionMember[#, point] &];
```

Select the positions of boundary vertices in the graph embedding :

```
boundary…vertices⎵positions = 
Select[VertexList[g] /. VertexPos, boundaryPoint];
```

The following is identical to method 1 and so has been copy pasted for convenience:

One may order these vertices along a path using [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html)

```
path…ordering = 
  FindCurvePath[boundary…vertices⎵positions];

path = boundary…vertices⎵positions[[path…ordering[[1]]]];
```

Then one may construct edges from those ordered points using [`PathGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PathGraph.html) and [`EdgeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeList.html). Note that we first had to order the edges before using `PathGraph`.

```
path⎵edges = path // PathGraph // EdgeList;
```

Those are written as spatial points we have to convert them back to vertex positions by inverting VertexPos above. We then add those edges to the original graph:

```
completed…graph = EdgeAdd[g, path⎵edges /. Reverse /@ VertexPos]
```

We can check the result with:

```
HighlightGraph[completed…graph, 
Style[#, RandomColor[]] & /@ EdgeList@completed…graph]
```

**Note**: some edges at the boundary might randomly have a similar color, evaluate the code again to change colors and check that the edges no longer have the same color.

[image]

```
KVertexConnectedGraphQ[completed…graph, 2]
```

`(* False *)`